Ошибка при создании проекта на Ruby on Rails(Couldn't find sqllite)
Впервые устанавливаю руби и рейлс. При создании нового проекта столкнулся с проблемой. Пробовал команду sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev и потом создать новый проект но не помогло.

Очень желательно сообщение об ошибке добавлять текстом, а не картинкой. Тогда его можно копировать. Вам нужно открыть файлик gem_make.out (полный путь в 4й строке на скрине) и посмотреть в полный лог установки гема, там будет более точно указано на возникшую ошибку


Тебе нужно прописать
sudo gem install sqlite3 -v 2.0.4

если не помогло ввести gem list и посмотреть какая версия sqlite3 у тебя установлена, и в Gemfile поменять на нее.

если шаг 1 и шаг 2 не помогли, то посмотри какая версия ruby и RoR у тебя стоит. Поставь предпоследние стабильные версии. И заново пропиши Gemfile. Вписывая каждый гем, нужно убедится, подходит ли его версия к ruby и RoR.


